# RemoveCallback from another location

Tags: java, android, handler

I have implemented a button which triggers a recurring event while still pressed using the instructions here:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5ce6d97956952472/50a625cc3cef1bec?lnk=gst&q=%22Auto+repeat+button%22&pli=1

```
Button buttonDown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDown);
    buttonDown.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction(); 
            if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                move(SOUTH);
                moveDirection = SOUTH;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTask, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 200); 
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This works perfectly. I would like other triggers in my program to stop the recurring event also. However placing `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);` doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This works: http://pastebin.com/qfWj7YuK and stops repeating in less then a second. Are you sure `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);` gets called? Log something out there too.

Comment: Thanks, it seems putting the call in a new thread helped. Not sure why...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by calling `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);` in it's own thread like so:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
  }
};
t.setDaemon(true);
t.start();
```

This seems very inefficient though, needing a new thread just to make this call.